# How can i get the value from the Dynamic query

Tags: database

```
$query=db_select('node','n');
$query->join('field_data_field_cmp_playerid','b','n.nid=b.entity_id');
$query->join('field_data_field_cmp_id','c','n.nid=c.entity_id');
$query->join('field_data_field_cmp_userscore','d','n.nid=d.entity_id');
$query->join('field_data_field_cmp_usersupport','e','n.nid=e.entity_id');
$query->join('field_data_field_cmp_status','f','f.entity_id=c.field_cmp_id_nid');
$query->join('field_data_field_cmp_attend_time','g',' g.entity_id = n.nid');
$query->join('field_data_field_cmp_end_date','h',' h.entity_id = c.field_cmp_id_nid');
$query->fields('n',array('title','nid'),'d',array('field_cmp_userscore_value'),'e',array('field_cmp_usersupport_value'),'f',array('feld_cmp_status_tid'),'g',array('.field_cmp_attend_time_value'),'h',array('field_cmp_end_date_value'));
$query->condition('b.field_cmp_playerid_uid',$userid,'=');
$query->condition('n.type','Campaign_PlayerList','=');
$result=$query->execute()->fetchAll();
```

i use foreach loop to get the value of the query

```
foreach($result as $value)
{
    drupal_set_message(t('The variable is %va',array('%va'=>$value->title)));
    drupal_set_message(t('The variable is %va1',array('%va2'=>$value->field_cmp_userscore_value)));
    drupal_set_message(t('The variable is %va2',array('%va2'=>$value->field_cmp_end_date_value)));
}
```

the value i get is  "title" and i can't get the field_cmp_userscore_value and field_cmp_end_date_value value.

what could the problem be?

Thank you

Comment: Have your tried displaying the content of the `field_cmp_userscore_value` like: `<pre>print_r($value->field_cmp_userscore_value);</pre>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`fields()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3Afields/7) member function of a [`SelectQuery`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21select.inc/class/SelectQuery/7) class only take two arguments: An alias and an array of fields. At the moment you're trying to add the fields from all tables in one go, when you need to split them up into separate calls to `fields()`:

```
$query->fields('n',array('title','nid'));
$query->fields('d',array('field_cmp_userscore_value'));
$query->fields('e',array('field_cmp_usersupport_value'));
$query->fields('f',array('field_cmp_status_tid'));
$query->fields('g',array('field_cmp_attend_time_value'));
$query->fields('h',array('field_cmp_end_date_value'));
```

There are also a couple of typos in your fields names:

1. `.field_cmp_attend_time_value` should be `field_cmp_attend_time_value`
2. `feld_cmp_status_tid` should be `field_cmp_status_id`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the following line is wrong:

```
$query->fields('n',array('title','nid'),'d',array('field_cmp_userscore_value'),'e',array('field_cmp_usersupport_value'),'f',array('feld_cmp_status_tid'),'g',array('.field_cmp_attend_time_value'),'h',array('field_cmp_end_date_value'));
```

You need to call fields() separately for each table. Right now, the additional arguments are ignored.

Also note that it is strongly recommended to use EntityFieldQuery to query field tables, that however has the limitation that you need to load the node object to get the field values.

Comment: `EntityFieldQuery` would indeed be much better for this particular job